# updated value of member variable is not reflacted within thread routin function in pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
void MyThread::startThread()
{
    bStopThread = 0;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachedstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&threadID, &attr, threadFunc, this);
}

void MyThread::stopThread()
{
    bStopThread = 1;
}

void* MyThread::threadFunc(void* arg)
{
    MyThread* myThread = reinterpret_cast<MyThread*>(arg);

    while(myThread->bStopThread == 0)
    {

    }
}
```

In above Code Sample, I am trying to get out of the while loop, implemented in thread routine function, when I call `stopThread` function. but when I am testing this code, my boolean variable is changed in `stopThread` function but its not reflected in thread routine function. Can anyone help me on this. What goes wrong here. I am compiling this code in android jni using NDK. I tried mentioning `volatile` type for `bStopThread` variable, but its not working as well.

Comment: Common causes for issues like this are 1) using an invalid object, and 2) using a different object than you assume that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be quite a few things that may cause this behavior.

- The compiler may decide to put this variable in a register and read and write to this register. Since a register is private to a thread, no thread changes made will be visible to any other thread.
- The compiler can see that you don't change the variable in threadFunc() and therefore reach a conclusion that only the initial state of bStopThread is important and there's no reason to inspect it further and optimize your code accordingly.
- The CPU can read and write this variable to its own cache and not to and from the main memory, therefore making changes to it invisible to other CPUs (other threads).

Usually volatile is enough to solve such problems but you write it did not work for you.

The easiest way to solve this would be to wrap the access to bStopThread with a mutex. That will ensure both the compiler and CPU "get the message" that this variable is for usage between threads and CPUs and should be treated accordingly.

Another similar option is to use atomic variables, e.g. std::atomic_bool.

If you are interested in learning more search the web for "Memory Coherency".

Comment: Using `volatile` isn't the proper way to synchronise access to concurrently accessed variables. Going for mutexes or atomics are the two possiblities to choose from.

Comment: @alk Synchronization is not really the problem here, but rather visibility. The timing, when the thread sees the change, is not important in this case. What is important is that it sees it, even if some time has passed since it was actually changed.

Comment: "Usually `volatile` is enough" - no, it isn't. It might make synchronisation issues less likely to happen, but it doesn't fix them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Like I wrote in response to alk, there's no synchronization problem here.

Comment: @selalerer: Yes there is, there's a data race due to unsequenced access to the same variable by two threads, giving undefined behaviour. There's no guarantee that the change from one thread will ever be seen in the other - as you say yourself, in the last bullet point. (Most current hardware does provide cache coherency, to avoid problems with the vast amount of broken code like this in the wild; so `volatile` will "fix" the problem by accident when running on that hardware. But that might become impractical in the near future, if the number of cores continues to increase.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour It makes sense that in any architecture there will be some kind of timeout of a cache line that will flush it to the main memory and mark this cache line dirty in other CPUs cache even when the CPU didn't perform it explicitly. I obviously don't know it will always be like this (or event that it is on all current archs).

Comment: @selalerer: It just about makes sense for today's mainstream architectures, with only a few cores. It requires communication channels between all the caches, so that each can invalidate lines in all the others. That doesn't scale well with the number of caches, and can't be expected to continue if that number increases significantly. If you rely on how your current CPU happens to treat undefined behaviour, then you're likely to have problems in the future.